# Castle Interception. How to specify kind of Proxy using fluent API and InterceptorAttribute

Tags: castle-windsor, castle-dynamicproxy, interception

Castle supports different [kinds of Dynamic Proxy](http://docs.castleproject.org/Tools.Kinds-of-proxy-objects.ashx). How can I setup kind of proxy to use, when

1. regestering a component with WindsorContainer
2. using InterceptorAttribute?

Comment: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Interceptors.ashx http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-Interceptors-ProxyOptions.ashx

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking help about. First read the docs @PhilDegenhardt linked then ask another question with the specific problem youa re encountering

Comment: When you add the InterceptorAttribute to a class that implements some interface and then resolve this interface, Castle create "interface proxy with target", but I would like to get "class proxy". This is my question - how to specify kind of proxy to create when adding interceptor to a class using InterceptorAttribute or Fluent API.